# Queueing of git post-receive hooks?

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I am looking to run a custom script on `git post-receive`, but am wondering how git behaves if / when multiple pushes are received in succession before the script from the first push finishes (or fails)? Do post-receive hooks queue?

Example scenario: Post-receive hook triggers a script to copy changed file(s) to a remote NFS share. This script may:

- take longer than a few seconds to complete
- fail if the NFS is unavailable
- network disruption could interrupt transfer, causing failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `receive-pack` program is what actually runs the `post-receive` hook.  The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-receive-pack.html) says, in part:

> Note that it is possible for refname to not have sha1-new when this hook runs. This can easily occur if another user modifies the ref after it was updated by git-receive-pack, but before the hook was able to evaluate it. It is recommended that hooks rely on sha1-new rather than the current value of refname.

Based on the source, the pack lock-file is removed *before* running the post-receive hook, which means that other updates (local or remote) can begin while the post-receive hook runs.

If you need queueing or locking (or both), you will have to implement that yourself.